# How to call a sibling method in an object defined with object syntax?

Tags: javascript

How to do this?

```
var obj = {
 func1 : function(){
   // Do stuff 
 },
 func2 : function(){
  func1();  // does not work
  this.func1();  // does not work
 }
}
```

Edit: missed a semicolon

Comment: `this.func1();` will work just fine if you invoke the `func2` function in the context of `obj`, i.e.: directly `obj.func2();`

Comment: You say "if you invoke the func2 function in the context of obj".  What would be an example of invoking it in a way that it wouldn't work?

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong.  this.func1() works fine in this code sample.  But see my answer for a caveat to be aware of.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var obj = {
 func1 : function(){
   // Do stuff 
 },
 func2 : function(){
  obj.func1();  // It works fine
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way of doing this without using the parent name?

Comment: @systemicplural, see my answer for using the 'this' keyword

Comment: In javascript object literal notation this is the only way. If you want use 'this', the hvgotcodes write appropriate way in non-literal javascript

Comment: You can use "this.func1()".  You don't need to use "obj.func1()" as this answer suggests.  But see my answer for a caveat to be aware of.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to use the 'this' keyword, you should do something like

```
function obj() {
    this.param = whatever;

}

obj.prototype.method1 = function(){
...
}

obj.prototype.method2 = function(){
    this.method1();
}
```

you could declare the methods in the obj function, but it is better to use prototype, because it is more efficient -- no matter how many obj instances you create, the functions only exist once.  If you put the functions in the obj constructor, each instance of obj has its own copy of the function.  javascript does some magic to associate the method call with the object instance on which it is called, to make sure 'this' means the right thing in context

Comment: I'm aware of this method, but the class is already written in object notation so I wondered if there was a way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the person asking the original question thought that wouldn't work.  Their example does work.

```
var obj = {
 func1 : function(){
   console.log("doing stuff");
 },
 func2 : function(){
  this.func1();  // works fine!
 }
}
```

You can paste that into the console and call `obj.func2()` and it works just fine.  You don't need to name the object in this situation.

But be careful.  This solution wouldn't work if you define *another* anonymous function inside of func2, and then try to use "this" inside of *that* function (such as if you're defining a callback). You'll get a "Uncaught TypeError: this.func1 is not a function" error.  The problem in that situation is that "this" no longer refers to the outer object, it now refers to the context of that new inner function. For example:

```
var obj = {
 func1 : function(){
   console.log("doing stuff");
 },
 func2 : function(){
   var func3 = function () {
     this.func1();  // doesn't work ("this" is no longer obj)
   }
   func3();
 }
}
```

To fix that issue, you could save a local copy of "this".  Example:

```
var obj = {
 func1 : function(){
   console.log("doing stuff");
 },
 func2 : function(){
   var ourThis = this;
   var func3 = function () {
     ourThis.func1(); // works fine!
   }
   func3();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create your object through a factory function. That way, you can initialize your functions and use them inside the others.

```
const objFactory = () => {
  const func1 = () => {
    // Do stuff
  }

  const func2 = () => {
    func1(); // This will work
  }

  return { func1, func2 }
}

const obj = objFactory();
obj.func1();
obj.func2();
```