# How to call a member function from another member function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have some code like this

```
function Chart(start, end, controller, method, chart)
{
    console.log('Chart constructor called');
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.controller = controller;
    this.method = method;
    this.chart = chart;
    this.options = {};
}

Chart.prototype.update = function()
{
    console.log('update ' + new Date().getTime());
    $.getJSON('index.php', {
        controller: this.controller,
        method: this.method,
        START: this.start,
        END: this.end },
        function(json) { this.draw(json); }); //<-- Problem right here!
}              

Chart.prototype.draw = function(json)
{
    //lots of code here
}
```

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'draw'`. Now, I'm the first to admit that I'm pretty new to Javascript. Am I supposed to call member functions in another way? Or  am I supposed to do something different altogether?

edit: Here is how I'm creating my object:

`chartObj = new Chart(start, end, 'OBF.RootCauses', 'ajaxRootCauses', chart);`

Comment: How are you invoking the method. Are you accidentally doing `var x = Chart()` instead of `var x = new Chart()`.

Comment: i am not very into JS at the time, but try to instnciate draw befor update ... maybe that'll do the trick

Comment: Welcome to the JavaScript this hell...as someone said this when you call draw refers to the context of the callback not your object

Comment: I've added how I'm creating the object. And helle, thanks, but I've tried changing the order of my function creation... no dice.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4947449/470749

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `this` is changed because you are defining a new function - so `this` refers to the function you are in.

There are other ways how to get around this, but the simplest way would be to save `this` to a variable and call the function on that variable, something like this:

```
Chart.prototype.update = function()
{
    console.log('update ' + new Date().getTime());
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON('index.php', {
        controller: this.controller,
        method: this.method,
        START: this.start,
        END: this.end },
        function(json) { self.draw(json); });
}
```

See Chris's answer for a different approach for solving the same problem.

Comment: And to put some code to the words, try: `console.log('update ' + new Date().getTime()); var self = this; $.getJSON('index.php', ...,
        function(json) { self.draw(json); });` :)

Comment: Yeah I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: That did it! A little puzzling to me... I'm not sure I see why `this` would suddenly work just because I assigned it to another variable. At any rate, it's working, and my charts have popped to life.

Comment: @2bits: Because `this` is a special variable that is set to the context a function is invoked in. By assigning the value of `this` to another variable you can refer to that value in another scope. An other of these "special variables" is `arguments`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can change this line

```
function( json ) { this.draw( json ); });
```

to this:

```
$.proxy( this.draw, this ) );
```

That will preserve the context where the function was called (i.e., the this variable).

Comment: That's really interesting. I'd have given it to you but Jakub answered first and it was for a more general case. You still get my upvote, though =)