# Calling member function from another member function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“this” keyword in event methods when using JavaScript prototype object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369004/this-keyword-in-event-methods-when-using-javascript-prototype-object)

I have created a class called `MyClass` in Javascript and bound the `onclick` event to a button on the page. When the `onclick` event fires I want to call another member function but it gives me undefined error. please help.

```
//MyClass constructor
MyClass = function() {

//Find search button
this.ctrlSearchButton = $("#btnSearch");

//Attach onclick event to search button
this.ctrlSearchButton.click(this.onSearchButtonClick);
};

MyClass.prototype.onSearchButtonClick = function () {
    DoSearch();// ERROR : Object Expected
};

MyClass.prototype.DoSearch = function () {
    alert("search called");
};
```

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4947449/470749

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.onSearchButtonClick = function () {
        self.DoSearch();// ERROR : Object Expected
    };
   this.DoSearch = function () {
       alert("search called");
    };
  ....
}
```

Comment: actually you could probably just move the MyClass.prototype declarations into the MyClass = function() method, so you can access this without needing the self declaration